# Get name of the day in a week from the day number. (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to figure out a way to get the name of the day (ex : Monday, Tuesday..) from the day number(ex :1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday..etc).

I have a `NSDictionary` structured like so.

```
{
close =     {
    day = 5;
    time = "22:00";
    dayName = "";
};
open =     {
    day = 5;
    time = "9:00";
    dayName = "";
};
}
```

I want to add the name of the day to this dictionary under the key "dayName"... where the value is the name of the day corresponding to the day number in the key "day".

Thank you :)

Comment: Well, you can make enumeration method that will return string depending on number switch(day)... case 1: return monday...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start by getting the names of the days:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSArray *daySymbols = dateFormatter.standaloneWeekdaySymbols;
```

Now, this is an array of weekday names where at index 0 is Sunday, therefore you will have to convert your indices.

```
NSInteger dayIndex = 1; // 1 = Monday, ... 7 = Sunday
NSString *dayName = daySymbols[dayIndex % 7];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString * closeDay=[[yourDictionary valueForKey:@"close"] valueForKey:@"dayName"];
NSString * openDay=[[yourDictionary valueForKey:@"open"] valueForKey:@"dayName"];
```

you can replace dayName with day if you want check it. I hope I help;

Answer (score -1):

Apply the enumuration and add the day in an array

```
NSString * closeDay=[[yourDictionary valueForKey:@"close"] valueForKey:@"dayName"];
NSString * openDay=[[yourDictionary valueForKey:@"open"] valueForKey:@"dayName"];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[arr addObject:openDay];
NSMutableArray *finalArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<[givenDic count];i++){
NSString *day= [self getDay:arr[i]];
NSMutableDictionary *dic= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setObject:day forKey:@"dayName"];
[finalArray addObject:dic];
}

-(NSString*)getDay:(NSString *)dayNo{
switch([dayNo intValue]){

case 1:
return Monday;
break;

case 2:
return Tuesday;
break;

case 3:
return Wednesday;
break;

case 4:
return Thursday;
break;

case 5:
return Friday;
break;

case 6:
return Saturday;
break;

case 7:
return Sunday;
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
[array addObject:@"1"];
[array addObject:@"2"];
[array addObject:@"5"];
[array addObject:@"4"];

NSMutableArray *mainArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for(int i=0; i< array.count;i++){
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    switch ([array[i] integerValue]) {
        case DayOne:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Sunday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        case DayTwo:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Monday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        case DayThree:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Tuesday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        case DayFour:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Wednesday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        case DayFive:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Thursday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        case DaySix:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Friday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        case DaySeven:
            [dict setObject:array[i] forKey:@"day"];
            [dict setObject:@"your time" forKey:@"time"];
            [dict setObject:@"Saturday" forKey:@"dayName"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [mainArray addObject:dict];
}
NSLog(@"%@",mainArray);
```

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,DayString) {
    DayOne = 1,
    DayTwo,
    DayThree,
    DayFour,
    DayFive,
    DaySix,
    DaySeven
};

Comment: Huh, if you are creating an `enum`, why don't you name the cases with human readable names? e.g. `Monday` instead of `DayOne`? Also, the Apple coding guidelines require you to name the cases `kDayStringMonday`, `kDayStringTuesday` etc. to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: Yes u right , that i understand , have to change member of enum for readable.